# How to return multiplicity of each eigenvalue?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I could not find the information so maybe someone know if it possible.

I have a matrix which has several degenerated eigenvalues and I would like Mathematica to return the multiplicity of each eigenvalue.

Is there any function doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Tally`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html):

```
ev = Eigenvalues[{{2, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}]
```

> {2, 2, 1, 1}

```
Tally @ ev
```

> {{2, 2}, {1, 2}}

Alternatively, [`Counts`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Counts.html):

```
Counts @ ev
```

> <|2 -> 2, 1 -> 2|>

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you !

Comment: @Kawette, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 2):

In exact arithmetic or symbolics, talking about eigenvalue multiplicity is fine. When inexact arithmetic is involved, things are a bit murkier.

As an example of something to be careful about, consider this modified example due to Forsythe:

```
mat = {{1, 0, -2^(-52)}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}};
```

Then,

```
Eigenvalues[mat] // N
   {1. + 5.24418*10^-6 I, 1. - 5.24418*10^-6 I, 0.999994}
```

but,

```
Eigenvalues[N[mat]]
   {1., 1., 1.}
```

Depending on your application, you might or might not consider the matrix to be nearly degenerate.

(Note that `2^(-52) == $MachineEpsilon`.)