# How can I use Tally in my code?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I a computing the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of a Laplacian on a unit square. I have written it as follows:

```
{ℒ, ℬ} = {-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}],DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]};
{vals, funs} = DEigensystem[{ℒ, ℬ}, u[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 8];
vals
```

Therefore, I have received the list of first $8$ eigenvalues, that is:

$\qquad \{2\pi^2,\, 5\pi^2,\, 5\pi^2,\, 8\pi^2,\, 10\pi^2,\, 10\pi^2,\, 10\pi^2,\, 10\pi^2 \}$.

Now I want to use `Tally` to find the multiplicity of a specific eigenvalue (for example, take the eigenvalue $5\pi^2$). I have no idea how to use `Tally` within the code written above. Please help me. I have read the reference  [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html#:%7E:text=tallies%20the%20elements%20in%20list,elements%20together%20with%20their%20multiplicities.&text=uses%20test%20to%20determine%20whether,class%2C%20together%20with%20their%20multiplicities.), but I have no idea how to use it in my case.

Please help me.

Comment: take a look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183096/how-to-return-multiplicity-of-each-eigenvalue

Comment: In general, I think `Counts` and `CountsBy` are more useful functions than `Tally`. `Tally` is a bit of a relic of the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tally` can certainly count the occurrances of eigenvalues in your list called `vals`. For instance `Tally[vals]` tells me that there are $2$ instances of $10 \pi^{2}$ and $2$ instance of $5 \pi^{2}$.

[image]

---

Looking at [`Tally`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html) in the documentation I see that the word "multiplicities" means the number of instances of each distinct element in a list.

[image]

---

I notice that your code is producing a different `vals` in my notebook! Please quit your kernel and re-evaluate!

[image]

---

Also Wolfram mentions this in his documentation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I want to know the multiplicity of a specific eigenvalue $5 \pi^2$. By "Multiplicity" I mean the dimension of eigenspace (number of linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to the specific eigenvalue). Are the the multiplicity of an eigenvalue and "Tally" same things?

Comment: sorry, I'm in a zoom meeting now. I'll get back to you in 2 hours. (maybe have a look at `Thread[{funs, vals}]`)

Comment: Upon reading different sources on google I'm $90$% certain that the "multiplicity" of $5\pi^{2}$ is $2$.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but I have some confusions that whether the "multiplicity" in the mathematica documentation same as the "multiplicity" defined in linear algebra (i.e. here by "multiplicity" we mean dimension of eigenspace or number of linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to the specific eigenvalue or please see the [link](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~xchen/teach/lin_alg/Eigen.pdf)). Can you please help me?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183096/how-to-return-multiplicity-of-each-eigenvalue

Comment: Thanks for your link. But my confusions is still there.Your link gives the idea about number of occurrence of a specific eigenvalue in the eigenvalue list. But, it does not tell about my confusions. My question is as follows: $\textbf{Is the "multiplicity" in the mathematica documentation same as the "multiplicity" defined in linear algebra (i.e. here by "multiplicity" we mean dimension of eigenspace or number of linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to the specific eigenvalue)?$

Comment: I'm not sure. Apparently there is both Algebraic multiplicity and Geometric multiplicity. I strongly suggest you analyze a simpler problem. Maybe an [example that is already solved](https://people.math.carleton.ca/~kcheung/math/notes/MATH1107/wk10/10_algebraic_and_geometric_multiplicities.html#:~:text=Algebraic%20multiplicity%20vs%20geometric%20multiplicity&text=In%20general%2C%20determining%20the%20geometric,a%20root%20of%20pA.) and calculate it by hand and then with `Tally`.